# Trying to optimize parameters in the Lugre Dynamic Friction model

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, physics, ode

I have data collected in CSV of every output of the friction model. the model imagines the contact between to surfaces as one dimensional bristles that react to being bent like springs this deflection. the force of friction is model as:

```
FL(V,Z) = sig0*Z +sig1*DZ/Dt +sig2*V
```

where V is the Velocity of the Surface Z is the deflection of the Bristles And DZ/Dt is the rate of deflection and is equal to:

```
DZ/Dt = V + abs(V)*Z/(Fc + (Fs-Fc)*exp(-(V^2/Vs^2))
      = V + abs(V)*Z/G(V)
      = V + H(V)*Z
```

Where Fc is the friction of the object in motion(constant), Fs is equal to the Force required to get the object into motion (a constant > Fc) and Vs is the total speed required to transition between the domains(a constant I've experimentally derived). the velocity and position of the block are provided in the CSV as well as the force of friction all with respect to time. I have also created an easily integrable approximation of the Velocity as a function of time (trigonometric).

On to the problem: the code throws a fit with the way I'm trying to pass lists in to the functions (I think).

The function the passes the parameters SEEMS to work (taken from a different file that simply plots the data the) however I've tried to numerically integrate the DZ/Dt and fit the sig parameters to the imported Friction data.

What I imported

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import optimize
import pylab as pp
from math import sin, pi, exp, fabs, pow
```

Parameters

```
Fc=2.7  #N
Fs=8.2  #N
Vs=.34  #mm/s
```

Initial_conditions

```
ITime=Time[0]
Iz=[0,0,0]
```

Building the friction model

```
def velocity(time):
    V=-13/2*1/60*pi*sin(1/60*pi*time+pi)       
    return V

def g(v,vs,fc,fs,sig0):
    G=(1/sig0)*(fc+(fs-fc)*exp(-pow(v,2)/pow(vs,2)))
    return G

def h(v,vg):
  H=fabs(v)/vg
  return H

def findz(z, time, sig):
  Vx=velocity(time)
  VG=g(Vx,Vs,Fc,Fs,sig)
  HVx=h(Vx,VG)
  dzdt=Vx+HVx*z
  return dzdt

def friction(time,sig,iz):
  dz=lambda z,time: findz(z,time,sig)
  z=odeint(dz,iz,time)
  return sig[0]*z+sig[1]*findz(z,time,sig[0])+sig[2]*velocity(Time)
```

Should return the difference between the Constructed function and the data and
yield a list containing the optimized parameters

```
def residual(sig):
  return Ff-friction(Time,sig,Iz)

SigG=[4,20,1]
SigVal=optimize.leastsq(residual,SigG)

print "parameter values are ",SigVal
```

This returns

```
line 56, in velocity
    V=-13/2*1/60*pi*sin(1/60*pi*time+pi)

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Is this to do with the fact that I am passing lists?

Comment: That's...an awful lot of code for a poorly defined question. When you say " the code throws a fit with the way im tryin to pass lists in to the functions (I think).", this is the piece that matters most. What is the input, what is the output, and how is it different from the expected output? Is there an error? If so, please provide the error. See: how to create a [mcve]

Comment: ill try to clear it up

Comment: does this question look clearer?

Comment: As you require functions from numpy, please use arrays instead of lists: Var = numpy.array([ ]) instead of Var = [ ].

Comment: So should i just pass the function variables into a situation like:      def F(x): var=numpy.array([x])

Comment: The post lacks explanation for how you compute `V` and also some example values of `Ff` and `Time` are missing. The code for `Velocity()` is the cause of the error. Your Velocity uses a time value, whereas you pass a whole list/ array (with multiple values) to `Velocity()` when you call it in `friction()`?

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, `Velocity()` ist the cause of the error that is most probably due to the fact that it uses a time value, whereas you pass a whole list/ array (with multiple values) to `Velocity()` when you call it in `friction()`.

Using some chosen values and after shortening you code and passing `ITime` instead of `Time` the code runs correctly but it is left to you to judge if this is analytically what you wanted to achieve. Below is my code:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from math import sin,  pi,  exp,  fabs

# Parameters
Fc = 2.7  #N
Fs = 8.2  #N
Vs = .34  #mm/s

# define test values for Ff and Time
Ff    = np.array([100, 50, 50])
Time  = np.array([10, 20, 30])

# Initial_conditions
ITime = Time[0]
Iz    = np.array([0, 0, 0])

# Building the friction model
V    = lambda                   t: (-13 / 2) * ( 1 / (60 * pi * sin(1 / 60 * pi * t + pi)))      
G    = lambda v, vs, fc, fs, sig0: (1 / sig0) * (fc + (fs - fc) * exp(-v**2 / vs**2))
H    = lambda               v, vg: fabs(v) / vg
dzdt = lambda         z,  t,  sig: V(t) + H(V(t), G(V(t), Vs, Fc, Fs, sig)) * z


def friction(t, sig, iz):
  dz = lambda z, t: dzdt(z, t, sig)
  z  = odeint(dz, iz, t)
  return sig[0]*z + sig[1]*dzdt(z, t, sig[0]) + sig[2]*V(t)

# Should return the difference between the Constructed function and the data
# and yield a list containing the optimized parameters

def residual(sig):

  return Ff-friction(ITime, sig, Iz)[0]

SigG   = np.array([4, 20, 1])
SigVal = optimize.leastsq(residual, SigG, full_output = False)

print("parameter values are ", SigVal )
```

Output:

```
parameter values are  (array([    4.        ,  3251.47271228, -2284.82881887]), 1)
```